# Selecting a JVM for an embedded streaming device

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, garbage-collection, jvm, streaming

We're developing a device that's basically a raspberry pi that reads file data, processes it, and streams data out of a USB device at a given frame rate.

Due to the nature of the features we're using, we can't totally eliminate garbage allocation, and our GC pauses for even minor, young generation GC are causing frame skips.

Right now we're using HotSpot JVM, but my understanding is that it's better suited to large heap sizes, our memory needs rarely go over 256mb, so I'm wondering if there's a better VM with garbage collection that can give us pauses less than 15ms on a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, we've decided that we're fighting uphill making the application do something it really wasn't built for, or at least, it's not worth the development resources to continue along that path.

Our current solution is to leave the application as it is, and live with the reality of garbage collection pauses so we don't hamstring future development of our application with a crazy amount of optimization. Let Java do what it was designed to do.

To stop pauses that are causing frame skips, we have instead opted to create a second, tiny buffer application, managed by our primary application via IPC.

Comment: Something you might want to give a try is Shenandoah from Red Hat. Aleksey Shipilëv was talking about this at JavaZone this week and said it would run on a Pi 3 and reduce pauses quite significantly. Since it's a single generation collector it may well be better for your application.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will really struggle with this.  You don't provide the flags you're using to start your JVM so it's not possible to recommend alternatives.

A well configured G1 collector with an application that does not generate constantly increasing long-life objects will avoid stop-the-world full GCs. However, your problem is that even minor GCs (which are typically very fast) are causing unacceptable latency.  Part of the problem is the speed of the memory bus on the Pi, which is not really that great.

We (Azul, who I work for) produce a pauseless collector (C4) but that is designed for machines with more resources.  It needs a minimum of 1Gb RAM and uses multiple cores to handle GC concurrently with application threads.

Comment: Ah, we were looking at Azul that as a solution, but the licensing costs were prohibitive, I didn't know it also needed a lot of RAM. FYI, we did switch our VM to zulu embedded and we did notice a performance boost, so at least there's that :).

Appreciate the insight on the G1 collector, we were hitting stop the world events when we profiled that, but we were also creating a ton of garbage in the background too quickly, so that makes sense.